# Usage of irace Package: Iterated Race for Automatic Algorithm Configuration

Tags: r, optimization

I’m trying to use the irace package in R to find the parameter settings for a genetic algorithm which I programmed in Java. I’m trying to follow the following tutorial: http://iridia.ulb.ac.be/irace/files/irace-comex-tutorial.pdf 
 and included example http://iridia.ulb.ac.be/~manuel/comex_workshop/acotsp-example.tar.gz

I have installed the package and set up my files similar to the example. When I try some commands in R, either in the example directory or my own problem folder, such as `irace.cmdline("--hook-run")` or `irace.cmdline("--config-file")` it will tell me:

```
Error: == irace == run program hook 'C:/Users/Christian/Desktop/acotsp-example/hook-run' is not executable
```

I don’t really understand how exactly I should modify the example in order to get it running. If someone has experience in using the irace package I would be thankful to get some advice.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

The hook-run file needs be a bat file for windows. I recommend you try to do it using linux, for example, using the [NSGA-II tutorial](http://iridia.ulb.ac.be/irace/tutorial/index.html#nsgaii).

To execute, I did install the R, after the package irace in the R. So, I did enter in R using a terminal, after I done the commands in the nsga-example folder:

- require(irace)
- irace.cmdline("--parallel 4")

and be happy :D

---

Update:
I created a repository to host some examples using Java and Python projects:
https://github.com/gres-ufpr/irace